# std::string::append crashes program with "std::bad_alloc"

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I have a text file which contains a list of data relating to name, position, and height. My program parses this data into a vector map, then uses this data to construct an xml file using `boost::property_tree`. The text file is about 3500 lines, and the program consistently crashes at line 1773 with:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Aborted (core dumped)
```

At first I thought maybe the size limit was being reached, but reading up on `std::string` shows that the target computer should be able to allocate the size required. Regardless, I decided to test with `std::string::size` , `std::string::length`, `std::string::capacity`, `std::string::max_size` which showed (respectively):

```
...
...
6572094845  6572094845 6626476032 9223372036854775807
6579537815  6579537815 6626476032 9223372036854775807
6586984998  6586984998 6626476032 9223372036854775807
6594436394  6594436394 6626476032 9223372036854775807
6601892003  6601892003 6626476032 9223372036854775807
6609351825  6609351825 6626476032 9223372036854775807
6616815856  6616815856 6626476032 9223372036854775807
6624284100  6624284100 6626476032 9223372036854775807
```

`std::string::capacity` was seen to increase once `std::string::length == std::string::capacity`.

gdb bt after compiling for debug:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007fd67037e921 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007fd6709d3957 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007fd6709d9ae6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007fd6709d9b21 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007fd6709d9d54 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007fd6709da2dc in operator new(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007fd670a6bb8b in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007fd670a6d133 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x000056104c176f3a in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffc0af8b9a8) at /home/code/hello_world/createWorld.cpp:224
```

Example line in text file being read:

```
713.258 235.418 ABCD1234567     2898
```

Code:

```c++
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    CreateWorld *newWorld = new CreateWorld();
    lastModelsParser *lastModels = new lastModelsParser();
    
    /*
      Code here reads creates ifs for xml data, 
      then reads xml successfully into a ptree
    */

    vector<lastModelsParser::lastModel> _lastModels;

    _lastModels = lastModels->getlastModels();

    uint16_t lastModelsEntry = 0;
    std::string newModelString;

    for(auto i:_lastModels){
        ptNewModel = newWorld->modelModifier(ptModel, 
            _lastModels.at(lastModelsEntry).pX,
            _lastModels.at(lastModelsEntry).pY,
            _lastModels.at(lastModelsEntry).name, 
            _lastModels.at(lastModelsEntry).height);

        boost::property_tree::xml_parser::write_xml_element(modelOSS, ptNewModel.front().first, ptNewModel.back().second, 1, xml_settings);
        
        newModelString.append(modelOSS.str());              // CRASHES HERE 
 
        lastModelsEntry++;        
    }

    // append to world.xml
    boost::property_tree::write_xml(worldOSS, ptWorld, xml_settings);           // write xml data into OSStreams
    boost::property_tree::write_xml(modelOSS, ptModel, xml_settings);           // write xml data into OSStreams   
    size_t worldPos = worldOSS.str().find("</world>");

    std::string newWorldString = worldOSS.str().insert(worldPos,newModelString+"\n\t");

    newWorldFile << newWorldString ;
    

    delete(lastModels);
    delete(newWorld);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Edit. Valgrind output**

1. `valgrind --tool=massif --massif-out-file=memleak.txt ./createNewWorld`

```
heap_tree=detailed
n2: 6636657886 (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
 n2: 6626476282 0x5160B89: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
  n2: 6626476282 0x5162131: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
   n0: 6626476033 0x149F38: main (in /home/code/hello_world/createNewWorld)
   n0: 249 in 2 places, all below massif's threshold (1.00%)
  n0: 0 in 2 places, all below massif's threshold (1.00%)
 n0: 10181604 in 18 places, all below massif's threshold (1.00%)
```

2. `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --verbose --log-file=valgrind-out_1.txt ./createNewWorld`

```
...
--4758-- memcheck GC: 1000 nodes, 0 survivors (0.0%)
--4758-- memcheck GC: 1000 nodes, 0 survivors (0.0%)
--4758-- memcheck GC: 1000 nodes, 0 survivors (0.0%)
--4758-- memcheck GC: 1000 nodes, 0 survivors (0.0%)
==4758== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0xee015040, 0x1b37d5041) (undefined)
```

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` shows that the memory is running out, the string is too large, what's the size of input file?

Comment: If `bad_alloc` isn't being thrown due to RAM exhaustion, then it's likely because your heap has been corrupted in such a way that future allocations fail.  I suggest running your program under valgrind (or similar) to see if it points out any illegal memory writes.

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin the size of the input file in bytes is 436192, and contains 3382 lines. How is memory running out when `std::string::size` < `std::string::max_size` ?

Comment: `std::string::max_size` is a perfect world value. It can exceed the amount of storage you have free if things have gone wrong somewhere and eaten up or fragmented your storage..

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks, I've run with valgrind and its tool massif. Output is too long to paste here, so I have edited the OP.

Comment: @user4581301 ah that's good to know thank you.

Comment: Giving that `size of the input file in bytes is 436192`, then your code mostly have logic bugs, then it consumes too much memory ~6GB

Comment: @jabroni Is your program 64-bit?  If so, then the issue is likely *not* have to do with memory exhaustion, but memory corruption.  A 64-bit program would need to allocate a gigantic amount of memory before seeing an actual out-of-memory condition.  You have a lot of code posted where we have no idea what is going on behind the scenes.  How about a simple 5 or 6 line program that simply reads the file and sees if `std::string` can actually handle all of those characters?

Comment: Also, off topic, but this: `CreateWorld *newWorld = new CreateWorld();
    lastModelsParser *lastModels = new lastModelsParser();` is unnecessary to create heap-based objects.  Simply: `CreateWorld newWorld;  lastModelsParser lasstModels;` is all that was needed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah my system is 64bit which is why I was confused as to why memory is running out. I just ran a "top" on it and damn does it quickly chew up memory. It's happening on each append. Could it be the whitespace? I shortened the program a little, but had to keep some info just for clarity. Essentially the part to look at is the method of appending to the string in the range base for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause for crash in this code was due to the following lines fibbonaci'ing itself on each iteration:

```
boost::property_tree::xml_parser::write_xml_element(modelOSS, ptNewModel.front().first, ptNewModel.back().second, 1, xml_settings);

newModelString.append(modelOSS.str());
```

So to explain:

1. On each iteration, the write_xml_element member function was writing into `modelOSS` then appending it to newModelString.
2. modelOSS is not "overwritten" and is instead appended to by default.
3. This appended stream is then appended onto newModelString.

Based off this, you can completely remove the line `newModelString.append(modelOSS.str());` and it will function as normal.

For example this is what was happening:

```
New entry = "A"
it = 0, modelOSS = "A", newModelString = "A"
New entry = "B"
it = 1, modelOSS = "A, B", newModelString = "A, A, B"
new entry = "C"
it = 2, modelOSS = "A, B, C", newModelString = "A, A, B, A, A, B, C"
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::string::max_size` is not the biggest string your system can allocate. It's only the biggest string the `std::string` class itself could represent at all, given unlimited continuous memory space.

You are exceeding already more than 6GB, and there's a good chance there is simply not enough memory left to do the copy necessary for the next re-alloc. DO you have the 13GB RAM required for that step, and do your configured kernel limits permit allocation (not even commitment yet!) of that much for a single process?

Just avoid storing everything in a single, long string, but partition it / write out much earlier. Then re-allocations only result in memory usage spikes up to 2x the biggest allocation, and not 2x your total current memory consumption.

Comment: hmmm, looks like I may have to refactor my program then and instead of appending one giant xml string, loop it to create the string and add it to the desired xml so it's done once per iteration. That's a lot of memory it's taking up for something that just needs to be quite small and run once.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#1  0x00007f64df15bba8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f64ddc36e20 in ?? () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007f64ddc44f26 in ?? () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007f64ddc44fe1 in std::terminate() () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007f64ddc45378 in __cxa_throw () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007f64ddc36a7d in ?? () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x00007f64ddcfbe1d in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) ()
   from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007f64ddcfe51b in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long) () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007f63f4627d2a in encoder::xxx::xxx(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, encoder::TileInfo, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, encoder::TileInfo> > > const&, encoder::TileInfo const&, encoder::CrossTileChapters&, encoder::AddDataInfo const&) ()
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

bool encoder::xxx::xxx(const std::map<std::string, TileInfo> &mapTileInfos,
const TileInfo &tileInfo, CrossTileChapters &languangeTileChapters, const AddDataInfo &addInfo)
{
...
std::string language = tileInfo.tileType;
std::string addPoiName = "";
auto langCode2name = addInfo.langCode2name;
if (langCode2name.find(language) != langCode2name.end()) {
addPoiName = langCode2name[language];
}
std::string labels = languangeTileChapters.labelChapter->GetLablesString();
...
unsigned int languangeTileLabelCount = languangeTileChapters.labelChapter->GetLabelCount();
unsigned int nativeLabelCount = poiTileChapters.labelChapter->GetNativeLabelCount();
int offset = -1;
bool isFounded = false;
offset = GetPOIOffset(poiTileChapters.pointChapter, addInfo.poiSiteID, isFounded, true);
if (isFounded) {
labels.insert(labels.end(), nativeLabelCount - languangeTileLabelCount - 1, '\0');
} else {
labels.insert(labels.end(), nativeLabelCount - languangeTileLabelCount, '\0');
}
labels += addPoiName;
labels += '\0';
languangeTileChapters.labelChapter->SetLablesString(labels);
return true;
}

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.